# How to access each instance of same container from host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I have three instance of same containerized app running on docker. So their port are same for all. I can access one of them using port forwarding at localhost:8080 but when I want to do same thing for other ones I got error. So I think, somehow I need to access each instance from different ip address to connect them from my docker host. How can I do that?

Comment: They can't all be using the same host port, because they'd conflict.  What `docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` options are you using exactly?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes they cant use same port thats why I want to attach ip address each one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do that. In case of someone else wants to achive this behaviour, I am writing down here the solution.

First example, you have three same container from couchbase image and you want to connect them in couchbase ui like each of them is seperated node.

1- Firstly you should open network interface for each container you want to deploy. Run below command on terminal.

1. `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.18.0.2 netmask 0xff000000`
2. `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.18.0.3 netmask 0xff000000`
3. `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.18.0.4 netmask 0xff000000`

2- IP adresses above will be static container ip addresses for each instance. To do that, you should create docker network.

```
docker network create -d bridge my-network --gateway 172.18.0.1 --subnet 172.18.0.0/24
```

3- Create containers from couchbase image.

1. `docker run -d --name cb1 --network my-network --ip 172.18.0.2 -p 172.18.0.2:8091-8096:8091-8096 -p 172.18.0.2:11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase`
2. `docker run -d --name cb2 --network my-network --ip 172.18.0.3 -p 172.18.0.3:8091-8096:8091-8096 -p 172.18.0.3:11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase`
3. `docker run -d --name cb3 --network my-network --ip 172.18.0.4 -p 172.18.0.4:8091-8096:8091-8096 -p 172.18.0.4:11210-11211:11210-11211 couchbase`

4- Then you can open one of couchbase ui in this browser and connect the other two container to cluster. For example, type 172.18.0.2:8091 in browser and connect the 172.18.0.3 and 172.18.0.4 containers.

5- I need this project for GoSDK. So for golang you can use "couchbase://172.18.0.2" connection string to connect your cluster.

Note: This ip addresses are choosen randomly, you can assign whatever you want.